# Delete a row with condition on the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to delete a row with `max(id)` from a table in `MySQL`.
I am using query::

```
 DELETE 
 FROM master 
 WHERE id=(
 SELECT MAX(id) 
 FROM master)
```

but getting `error No. 1093`.

Can anybody please help me??

Comment: You cant modify the same table from which you are selecting the data in subquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 6):

You can't specify target table for `update` in `FROM` clause.

you can delete the last row as mentioned below.

```
 DELETE FROM master ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant modify the same table from which you are selecting the data in subquery.

Try this -

```
DELETE m.*
FROM master m 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id_temp from(
SELECT MAX(id) as id_temp 
FROM master) x)
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can't specify target table for `Delete` in `FROM clause`

Try this

```
DELETE FROM master 
WHERE id IN (SELECT A.MAXid FROM 
               (SELECT MAX(id) as MAXid FROM master) A
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Test WHERE id IN(SELECT MAX(id) FROM Test);
```

This seems to be cross SQL vendor friendly. The LIMIT option in MySQL becomes this in SQL SERVER.

```
 DELETE FROM Test WHERE id IN(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Test ORDER BY id DESC );
```

See [here](http://rextester.com/BYTZ74954)